# Need Help For VBScript Regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

I wannt to build VbScript regex for string having format like

```
XX-XX-XX-XX
XX= \w (Alphanumeric)
Note : Number of Hyphen are dynamic.
```

Sample i/p 
ABSCD123
ABC-123
ABC-234-PQ3
A-B-C

I created something like

```
^\w+\-*\w+$
```

But it is not working.Can anybody help me?

Comment: `^\w{2}-*\w{2}-*\w{2}-*\w{2}$`?

Comment: When you say the number of hyphens are dynamic, do you mean the number between words, or the number of words.  So is `XX------XX` possible or is `XX-X-XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XX-XX` what you meant?

Comment: @juharr yes `XX-X-XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XX-XX` possible  Sample Data  `44101766-0142662261`  
`441-01-766-01-42662-261`
`ABC-A-B-C34`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to group the first "word" with the hyphen

```
^(\w+\-)*\w+$
```

This assumes that you want to match things like

```
XX-XX
XXX-X
XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
XXX
```

But not

```
XX-
XX--XX
```

If there has to be a hyphen then this would work

```
^(\w+\-)+\w+$
```

Comment: ^(\w+\-)*\w+$ is not working with i/p query  aa-12. Any idea?

Comment: Are you saying you want to match the "aa-12" part in a string of "i/p query aa-12"?  If so then just remove the anchors ^ and $.